# Highcharts - Highroller including javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts in combination with high roller to render charts.

To define properties to charts in high roller it's usually very simple:

```
$this->chart->xAxis->labels->rotation= 55;
$this->chart->xAxis->labels->align= 'left';
```

becomes something like this:

```
"labels":{"rotation":55,"align":"left"}
```

The problem is that I'd like to include a js function, like this:

```
events: {
    load: Highcharts.drawTable
},
```

The problem is that if I include a function like I would do for any other property highroller will wrap it in quotes. I assume it does this because it's technically a string. 
For integers it seems highcharts removes the quotes.

So question in short: How to add a function in the events->load with highroller.

I want to use this to render a data table with the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Althought not quite the same as a load function, Highroller has an example of how to add a tooltip formatter function. The same approach should work for a load function. The basic approach is to add the function in javascript rather than in php. https://github.com/jmaclabs/HighRoller/blob/master/README.md

```
var myChartOptions = <?php echo $linechart->getChartOptionsObject()?>

  // define your own formatter for tooltip
  myChartOptions.tooltip.formatter = function() {
  return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
      Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e', this.x) + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, ',') + ' views';
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The code got into quotes because the json encode function puts quotes around eeeeverything.

Since highroller is no longer in development I've taken the liberty of adding a custom part to highroller removing quotes when a parameters is given.